# How can I get my User Interface to Update once there's a change in my MSSQL Database?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, hibernate, optaplanner

I am developing a Simple Warehouse Management System using Quarkus, Hibernate, MSSQL and OptaPlanner. I am wanting Customer Orders assigned to a Stock Location when I hit the 'Solve' button. When my System solves (using constraints), the StockLocationID will be put against the ShopifyOrders for e.g CustomerOrder1(PK) will be assigned to StockLocationID(FK) = 26.

It has successfully updated in the Database, however the data is supposed to be retrieved back and reflected on to my User Interface and I am not sure why. I have been using the [quarkus-school-timetabling](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/quarkus-school-timetabling) example (OptaPlanner) and now have this issue where its not reflecting the Changes from my Database into my UI.

Could this be an issue with my JavaScript file? If I use demo data it works perfectly fine, but since I am using my own Database it does not work.

Here is my current javascript file:

```
function refreshAllDetails() {
  $.getJSON("/allDetails", function (allDetails) {
    refreshSolvingButtons(allDetails.solverStatus != null && allDetails.solverStatus !== "NOT_SOLVING");
    $("#score").text("Score: " + (allDetails.score == null ? "?" : allDetails.score));

    const allDetailsByRoom = $("#allDetailsByRoom");
    allDetailsByRoom.children().remove();
    const allDetailsByProductSKU = $("#allDetailsByProductSKU");
    allDetailsByProductSKU.children().remove();
    const allDetailsByProductName = $("#allDetailsByProductName");
    allDetailsByProductName.children().remove();
    const unassignedShopify = $("#unassignedShopify");
    unassignedShopify.children().remove();

    const theadByRoom = $("<thead>").appendTo(allDetailsByRoom);
    const headerRowByRoom = $("<tr>").appendTo(theadByRoom);
    headerRowByRoom.append($("<th>Picking Station</th>"));
    $.each(allDetails.roomList, (index, room) => {
      headerRowByRoom
          .append($("<th/>")
              .append($("<span/>").text(room.name))
              .append($(`<button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 btn btn-light btn-sm p-1"/>`)
                  // .append($(`<small class="fas fa-trash"/>`)
                  .click(() => deleteRoom(room))));
    });
    const theadByProductSKU = $("<thead>").appendTo(allDetailsByProductSKU);
    const headerRowByProductSKU = $("<tr>").appendTo(theadByProductSKU);
    headerRowByProductSKU.append($("<th>Stock Location</th>"));
    const productSKUList = [...new Set(allDetails.shopifyList.map(shopify => shopify.productSKU ))];
    $.each(productSKUList, (index, productSKU) => {
      headerRowByProductSKU
          .append($("<th/>")
              .append($("<span/>").text(productSKU)));
    });
    const theadByProductName = $("<thead>").appendTo(allDetailsByProductName);
    const headerRowByProductName = $("<tr>").appendTo(theadByProductName);
    headerRowByProductName.append($("<th>Stock Location</th>"));
    const productNameList = [...new Set(allDetails.shopifyList.map(shopify => shopify.productName))];
    $.each(productNameList, (index, productName) => {
      headerRowByProductName
          .append($("<th/>")
              .append($("<span/>").text(productName)));
    });

    //Chnage productSKU to stockLocation
    const tbodyByRoom = $("<tbody>").appendTo(allDetailsByRoom);
    const tbodyByProductSKU = $("<tbody>").appendTo(allDetailsByProductSKU);
    const tbodyByProductName = $("<tbody>").appendTo(allDetailsByProductName);
    $.each(allDetails.stockLocationList, (index, stockLocation) => {
      const rowByRoom = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbodyByRoom);
      rowByRoom
        .append($(`<th class="align-middle"/>`)
          .append($("<span/>").text(`${stockLocation.stockLocation }`)
              .append($("<br><em>").text(`SKU: ${stockLocation.productSKU}`)
            .append($(`<button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 btn btn-light btn-sm p-1"/>`)))));
             // .append($(`<small class="fas fa-trash"/>`)
            //  .click(() => deleteStockLocation(stockLocation))))));

      const rowByProductSKU = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbodyByProductSKU);
      rowByProductSKU
        .append($(`<th class="align-middle"/>`)
          .append($("<span/>").text(`
                    ${stockLocation.productSKU}
                `)));
      $.each(allDetails.roomList, (index, room) => {
        rowByRoom.append($("<td/>").prop("id", `stockLocation${stockLocation.id}room${room.id}`));
      });
      const rowByProductName = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbodyByProductName);
      rowByProductName
        .append($(`<th class="align-middle"/>`)
          .append($("<span/>").text(`
                    ${stockLocation.tower}
                `)));

      $.each(productSKUList, (index, productSKU) => {
        rowByProductSKU.append($("<td/>").prop("id", `stockLocation${stockLocation.id}productSKU${convertToId(productSKU)}`));
      });

      $.each(productNameList, (index, productName) => {
        rowByProductName.append($("<td/>").prop("id", `stockLocation${stockLocation.id}productName${convertToId(productName)}`));
      });


    });

    $.each(allDetails.shopifyList, (index, shopify) => {
      const color = pickColor(shopify.productSKU);
      const lessonElementWithoutDelete = $(`<div class="card lesson" style="background-color: ${color}"/>`)
        .append($(`<div class="card-body p-2"/>`)
          .append($(`<h5 class="card-title mb-1"/>`).text(shopify.customerName))
          .append($(`<p class="card-text ml-2 mb-1"/>`)
            .append($(`<p class="card-text ml-2"/>`).text(`SKU: ${shopify.productSKU}`)
          .append($(`<small class="ml-2 mt-1 card-text text-muted align-bottom float-right"/>`).text(shopify.shopifyID))
          .append($(`<br><em>`).text(`Name: ${shopify.productName}`)))));
      const lessonElement = lessonElementWithoutDelete.clone();
      lessonElement.find(".card-body");
        //$(`<button type="button" class="ml-2 btn btn-light btn-sm p-1 float-right"/>`)
          //.append($(`<small class="fas fa-trash"/>`)
          //.click(() => deleteShopify(shopify)

      if (shopify.stockLocation == null || shopify.room == null) {
        unassignedShopify.append(lessonElement);
      } else {
        $(`#stockLocation${shopify.stockLocation.id}room${shopify.room.id}`).append(lessonElement);
        $(`#stockLocation${shopify.stockLocation.id}productSKU${convertToId(shopify.productSKU)}`).append(lessonElementWithoutDelete.clone());
        $(`#stockLocation${shopify.stockLocation.id}productName${convertToId(shopify.productName)}`).append(lessonElementWithoutDelete.clone());

      }
    });
  });
}

function convertToId(str) {
  // Base64 encoding without padding to avoid XSS
  return btoa(str).replace(/=/g, "");
}

function solve() {
  $.post("/allDetails/solve", function () {
    refreshSolvingButtons(true);
  }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    showError("Start solving failed.", xhr);
  });
}

function refreshSolvingButtons(solving) {
  if (solving) {
    $("#solveButton").hide();
    $("#stopSolvingButton").show();
    if (autoRefreshIntervalId == null) {
      autoRefreshIntervalId = setInterval(refreshAllDetails, 2000);
    }
  } else {
    $("#solveButton").show();
    $("#stopSolvingButton").hide();
    if (autoRefreshIntervalId != null) {
      clearInterval(autoRefreshIntervalId);
      autoRefreshIntervalId = null;
    }
  }
}

function stopSolving() {
  $.post("/allDetails/stopSolving", function () {
    refreshSolvingButtons(false);
    refreshAllDetails();
  }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    showError("Stop solving failed.", xhr);
  });
}


function showError(title, xhr) {
  const serverErrorMessage = !xhr.responseJSON ? `${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}` : xhr.responseJSON.message;
  console.error(title + "\n" + serverErrorMessage);
  const notification = $(`<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" style="min-width: 30rem"/>`)
    .append($(`<div class="toast-header bg-danger">
                 <strong class="mr-auto text-dark">Error</strong>
                 <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
               </div>`))
    .append($(`<div class="toast-body"/>`)
      .append($(`<p/>`).text(title))
      .append($(`<pre/>`)
        .append($(`<code/>`).text(serverErrorMessage))
      )
    );
  $("#notificationPanel").append(notification);
  notification.toast({delay: 30000});
  notification.toast('show');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  ;


  // Extend jQuery to support $.put() and $.delete()
  jQuery.each(["put", "delete"], function (i, method) {
    jQuery[method] = function (url, data, callback, type) {
      if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
      }
      return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
      })
    };
  });

  $("#refreshButton").click(function () {
    refreshAllDetails();
  });
  $("#solveButton").click(function () {
    solve();
  });
  $("#stopSolvingButton").click(function () {
    stopSolving();
  });

  refreshAllDetails();
});
```

Would it have something particularly to do with this Function in my JavaScript file?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  ;


  // Extend jQuery to support $.put() and $.delete()
  jQuery.each(["put", "delete"], function (i, method) {
    jQuery[method] = function (url, data, callback, type) {
      if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
        type = type || callback;
        callback = data;
        data = undefined;
      }
      return jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: method,
        dataType: type,
        data: data,
        success: callback
      })
    };
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean that you're writing to the database while the solver is solving ?

Comment: @sudo yes so after writing to the database through clicking the solve button, i want to reflect the changes on to my UI. But for some strange reason, UI wont reflect the changes from my database.

Comment: @Sabrina given you are using REST API to connect the UI to the backend, I would recommend:
1/ writing tests to make sure the backend works as expected
2/ debug the javascript (e.g. via developer tools available in a browser)